# Unable to get the number of columns and rows of a Mat

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, c++-cli, computer-vision

I am facing to a very weird situation where I am unable to get the number of `cols()` and `rows()` of a Mat. Following is my code:

```
    current = new Mat();


    int cols = current->cols();
    int rows = current->rows();
```

The `current` is a pointer and declared in the header file. It is necessary to keep it as a pointer.

Whenever the code reaches the place where I try to get `cols()` and `rows()` I get the following error twice, one per each method

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

I tried different ways like `(*current).cols()` but they did not help because that was another error.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cols` and `rows` are properties, not methods, therefore you can just use:

```
 int cols = current->cols;
 int rows = current->rows;
```